# Scrape Dynamic Data in Fangraphs

Tags: html

I know very little about programming. I just know that scrape exists, but it's impossible to write code for it, so I tried it with the help of chatGPT.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKanG.jpg)

I want to scrap this information in https://www.fangraphs.com/tools/wpa-inquirer

Follow the 5 dropdowns from Run environment to Run differential. The gray background values ​​below change. I would like to collect those values ​​that vary depending on five conditions.

I asked ChatGPT a question, got the code, and ran it. An example of the result I want is as shown in the following photo.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjRJg.jpg)

However, even though I ran the code, I could not get the desired result. The most positive result was that there were no errors in code execution, but the Home/Away win rate and LI values ​​remained unchanged, possibly because the drop-down value could not be changed.

The code using Selenium was roughly similar to the following.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/tools/wpa-inquirer'
driver.get(url)

def get_leverage_index(run_env, base_situation, inning, outs, run_differential):
    select_dropdown('rcbRun', run_env)
    select_dropdown('rcbBase', base_situation)
    select_dropdown('rcbInning', inning)
    select_dropdown('rcbOuts', outs)
    select_dropdown('rcbScore', run_differential)

    leverage_index = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td[text()="Leverage Index"]/following-sibling::td').text
    return leverage_index

def select_dropdown(dropdown_id, value):
    input_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"#{dropdown_id}_Input")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", input_element, value)

data = []

run_env_values = ['3.0', '3.5', '4.0', '4.5', '5.0', '5.5', '6.0', '6.5']
base_situation_values = ['_ _ _', '1 _ _', '_ 2 _', '1 2 _', '_ _ 3', '1 _ 3', '_ 2 3', '1 2 3']
inning_values = ['1 (Top)', '1 (Bottom)', '2 (Top)', '2 (Bottom)', '3 (Top)', '3 (Bottom)',
                 '4 (Top)', '4 (Bottom)', '5 (Top)', '5 (Bottom)', '6 (Top)', '6 (Bottom)',
                 '7 (Top)', '7 (Bottom)', '8 (Top)', '8 (Bottom)', '>= 9 (Top)', '>= 9 (Bottom)']
outs_values = ['0', '1', '2']
run_differential_values = ['-10', '-9', '-8', '-7', '-6', '-5', '-4', '-3', '-2', '-1', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

progress_count = 0

for run_env in run_env_values:
    for base_situation in base_situation_values:
        for inning in inning_values:
            for outs in outs_values:
                for run_differential in run_differential_values:
                    progress_count += 1
                    print(f'({progress_count}/{len(run_env_values) * len(base_situation_values) * len(inning_values) * len(outs_values) * len(run_differential_values)})')
                    leverage_index = get_leverage_index(run_env, base_situation, inning, outs, run_differential)
                    data.append([run_env, base_situation, inning, outs, run_differential, leverage_index])

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Run Environment', 'Base Situation', 'Inning', 'Outs', 'Run Differential', 'Leverage Index'])
df.to_excel('leverage_index_data.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are ready to extract data you can get the html content from the table.

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

html_content = driver.page_source

soup = bs(html_content, 'html.parser')
tbls = soup.find_all('table')
tbl = tbls[-1]

data = []

for row in tbl.find_all('tr'):
    row_data = []
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        input_tag = cell.find('input', class_='rcbInput')
        if input_tag and 'value' in input_tag.attrs:
            row_data.append(input_tag['value'].strip())
        else:
            row_data.append(cell.get_text(strip=True))
    data.append(row_data)

data = [row for row in data if any(row)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```